# How can I connect a Gtkmm signal to a fuction in another class?

Tags: c++, gtkmm3

I am new to c++ and Gtkmm3. I need to set signal in another class, how would I do that with out loading the class with the function in the class with the widget.

I dont want to reload the whole of FixedLayout in ButtonBox

*in class ButtonBox* **I dont want**

```
FixedLayout instance;
instance.move_widget();
```

The following shows my code

**layout.cpp**

```
#include "layout.h"
#include <iostream>

FixedLayout::FixedLayout()
{
    fixed.put(box, 0, 0);
    add(fixed);
}

void FixedLayout::move_widget(int x, int y)
{
    fixed.move(*fixed.get_focus_child(), x, y);
}

ButtonBox::ButtonBox()
{
    set_size_request(320, 480);
    header.set_size_request(-1, 24);
    body.set_size_request(-1, 456);
    pack_start(header);
    dragger = Gtk::GestureDrag::create(header);
    dragger->set_button(GDK_BUTTON_PRIMARY);
    dragger->set_propagation_phase(Gtk::PHASE_BUBBLE);
    dragger->signal_drag_update().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ButtonBox::update_drag));
    pack_end(body);
}

void ButtonBox::update_drag(bool x, bool y)
{
    FixedLayout::move_widget(x, y);
}
```

**layout**.h

```
#ifndef FIXEDLAYOUT_H
#define FIXEDLAYOUT_H

#include <gtkmm.h>

class ButtonBox: public Gtk::VBox
{
    public:
    ButtonBox();

    protected:
        Gtk::Button header{"Header"}, body{"Body"};
        Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::GestureDrag> dragger;
        void update_drag(bool x, bool y);

    private:
};

class FixedLayout: public Gtk::ScrolledWindow
{
    public:
       FixedLayout();
        //virtual ~bar();

    protected:
        void move_widget(int x, int y);
        Gtk::Fixed fixed;
        ButtonBox box;

    private:
};

#endif // FIXEDLAYOUT_H
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dragger->signal_drag_update().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ButtonBox::update_drag));
```

Here is how you connect a signal to a callback method. `this` is the pointer to the actual instance of the class. So how to connect to an instance of another class?

**Using a pointer**

If you need to connect a signal to a method of another class instance, you need to provide a pointer to that instance instead of `this`. Something on the line of:

```
signal().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*p, &::callback_name));
```

Here `p` is a generic pointer, make it an attribute of your class. Be aware that this makes the two class interdipendent, so is generally not a good idea if you want to make your code reusable.

In your case, you need to put a pointer to a `FixedLayout` instance in `ButtonBox`.

```
class ButtonBox: public Gtk::VBox
{
    private: #could be whatever
    FixedLayout *ptofl;

};
```

And in your constructor:

```
whatever_signal().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*ptofl, &FixedLayout::name_of_the_method));
```

**Inheritance**

Another way could be to make `ButtonBox` child of `FixedLayout`:

```
class ButtonBox: public Gtk::VBox, public FixedLayout
```

You need to invert the order definition of the two classes. Then from `ButtonBox` you can access protected and public methods of `FixedLayout` and in your code you can use `ButtonBox` instances only. When connecting the signals to a callback, you can use the `this` pointer as usual.